# Computing sum of an observable array nested in an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have demonstrated my problem in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sljux/zVg7R/3/

I have an array of objects. For simplicity, lets say each object has a name, and an array of values, all observable:

```
self.array = [
    {
        name: ko.observable("first"),
        values: ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3])
    },
    {
        name: ko.observable("second"),
        values: ko.observableArray([2, 3, 4])
    },
    {
        name: ko.observable("third"),
        values: ko.observableArray([3, 4, 5])
    }
];
```

From that array I need to filter out certain objects, and add an additional computed to each one, which computes the sum of all values. The filtering part isn't important to the problem, so it won't be done. The problem is that the observable needs to be a property of each object, and it needs to reference that object's `values` array.

My best try was:

```
self.newArray = ko.observableArray([]);

for(var i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
        name: ko.observable("new " + self.array[i].name()),
        values: ko.observableArray(self.array[i].values())
    };

    obj.sum = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var res = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < obj.values().length; j++)
                res += obj.values()[j];

            return res;
        },
        owner: obj
    });

    self.newArray.push(obj);
}
```

The problem is that the reference to the `values` observable array is somehow lost. That is, on the first computing, each object gets the sum of **his** values, but in the end, each computed computes the sum of the **last** object in array.

I tried with, and without the `owner` part of the computed, the reference is still transferred. The bug is obviously visible in the fiddle, where I have set up three buttons that change each values array.

I also tried setting it up as a class:

```
function Obj(name, values) {
    ...
}

self.newArray.push(new Obj("first", [1, 2, 3]);
```

but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort answer: use  `ko.utils.arrayForEach` instead of the manual `for` loop:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.array, function(item) {
    var obj = {
        name: ko.observable("new " + item.name()),
        values: ko.observableArray(item.values())
    };

    obj.sum = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var res = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < obj.values().length; j++)
                res += obj.values()[j];

            return res;
        },
        owner: obj
    });

    self.newArray.push(obj);
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6z4V/).

Long answer: you've bitten by the fact that in JavaScript the variables are function scoped so your `for` loop it **does not** create three local `obj` variable but reuses the same **one** variable and this combined with how closures work you will end up with all your computed referencing the last value:

You can solve this with wrapping the `for` body in an immediately executed function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
    (function(){
    var obj = {
        name: ko.observable("new " + self.array[i].name()),
        values: ko.observableArray(self.array[i].values())
    };

    obj.sum = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var res = 0;

            for (var j = 0; j < obj.values().length; j++)
                res += obj.values()[j];

            return res;
        },
        owner: obj
    });

    self.newArray.push(obj);
    })();
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSwQU/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm still getting used to JavaScript scopes. I actually did use `ko.utils.arrayForEach`, but only for computing the sum.